# Springboot WebClient timeout customization

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netty, spring-webclient

I'm using Spring boot Webclient (with Netty as httpClient) to make http calls.

I would like to configure the `idle time out` to align it with the remote server and avoid some IO issues. This timeout needs to be set on the ConnectionProvider

Reading the doc and code :

- [ref doc put some sample](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webflux-webclient/client-builder.html#webflux-client-builder-reactor-timeout) showing the creation of a httpClient
- in the same doc, we saw that by default we run using globalResources but the first example seems to lose a part of the default conf (the one using the constructor `new ReactorClientHttpConnector(reactorResourceFactory, mapper::configure)`)
- in the code, I saw `ClientHttpConnectorConfiguration` and the process of creating the httpClient using `the ConnectionProvider inside the ReactorResourceFactory`

Is there a best practice to configure something inside the ConnectionProvider ?

If I'm using the sample from the [Netty doc](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/reference/index.html#http-client-timeout) will I miss the application of some Spring defaults config (mappers on httpClient, globalUseResources, eventLoop config) ? It seems I will rely on the default netty configuration and not anymore on Spring's one. Perhaps I missed something.

Thanks